# How do i get the doc type update functionality when i combine it with a script type update?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using ES v7.3 and i am performing a "doc" and an "script" type update both for specific reasons but i wanted to combine both of these requests into one with the same functionality that they provide individually so please help me with that. I was not getting the desired "doc" type update functionality here as the document was getting overridden but i want it to partially update the doc. so please suggest a different approach.

"doc" update request:

```
POST test/_update/Z_nM_2wBjkGOA-r6ArOb
{
"doc": {
"CD" : {
  "name" : "yash",
  "tech" : "ES"
},
"PD" : {
  "name" : "tandon",
  "company" : "google"
}
},
"doc_as_upsert" : "true"
}
```

Used this update request to partially update my doc's as this request does not override the existing objects as it only updates the new added fields and add the new ones.

"script" type update:

```
POST test/_update/Z_nM_2wBjkGOA-r6ArOb
{
"scripted_upsert": true,
"script": {
"lang": "painless",
"source": "int getIndex(def x, def y){for(int i=0; i < x.length; i++) { if (x[i].model == y.model){return i}} return -1} if(!ctx._source.containsKey('nested_field')){ctx._source['nested_field']=[]} for(int tmp = 0 ; tmp< params.iterate.length;tmp++){  int y = getIndex(ctx._source.nested_field, params.iterate[tmp].object); if(y >= 0){ctx._source.nested_field.remove(y)} ctx._source.nested_field.add(params.iterate[tmp].object)}",
"params": {
  "iterate":[
    {
      "object": {
       "model": "nano",
        "value": 10
      }
    },
    {
      "object" : {
        "model" : "xuv",
        "value" : 9
      }
    },
    {
      "object" : {
        "model" : "tuv",
        "value" : 100
      }
    }
    ]
 }},
 "upsert" : {}
 }
```

in this script type update i am updating a nested type field and appending new objects into it.

Now if anyone can help me with making both of these individual request into one request and with maintaining both of theirs functionality that would be great.

Comment: that question did not had a satisfactory answer so i have spelled it differently here also i would appreciate if u could help me.

Comment: when i tried integrating the doc type update in script then it was not giving desired results as the doc was getting overridden every time a new request was made as so i am looking for another answer to this. I was not getting the "doc" update desired behavior here.

Comment: I have edited the question hence i would request you to please remove this duplicate mark so that someone could help.

Comment: hey, why are you not removing this duplicate tag now. U r not letting others answer the question neither you are answering it.